# routes for sub domains with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using only AngularJS is it possible to detect sub domains and route accordingly?

Say the subdomain *spicy.example.com* is pointing to the same docRoot as *example.com*

*example.com*  has an `index.html` where lives `<div ng-view></div>`

In my config I define routes for partials:
`$routeProvider.when('/food', {templateUrl: 'views/example.com/regular.html'});`

But what if *spicey.example.com* want's to override the `regular.html` partial with it's own?
`$routeProvider.when('/food', {templateUrl: 'views/spicy.example.com/hot.html'});`

Is this possible without using rewrite rules on a server like Apache/Nginx?

**Note:**
This is a single Single Page App
`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

I'm using CORS:
`$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;`

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible because of [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

> Keep in mind that Same Origin Policy applies to included resources
>   (e.g. ngInclude won't work for cross-domain requests on all browsers
>   and for file:// access on some browsers).

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

Comment: I'm not sure what SOP has to do with it. If I am on `spicy.example.com` and I am requesting a resource from `example.com/views/spicy.example.com/` I am not making a cross origin request to execute an action, I am just making a request for a resource.

Comment: you should have same host, same port and same protocol for making the request. in that case you are violating the host rule. so it is cross origin request.

Comment: I think we may be talking about different things. Think about partials the same way you think about js assets. Surely you can fetch jquery from a CDN the same way you can fetch a partial.

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a single page app using pushState.

Comment: you load js files from cdn using <script> tag in html. but angular makes ajax call for loading partials. they are not the same things.

Comment: What if I set `$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;` globally?

Comment: Enabling CORS is independant of security risks associated with application architecture. Also, resource sharing can be limited by whitelisting domains. It is no wonder even IE10 has enabled CORS support, being the last of the major browsers to adopt, eventually phasing out JSONP methods --- which are actually more insecure.

Answer (score 0):

CORS seems like the way to go.

You can either proxy pass the request to the files through NGINX / Node.js and enbale CORS, or you can use a CDN to serve the assets with CORS enabled like Amazon Cloud S3.

If the sumdoamins are pointing to the same doc root however, accessing:

```
example.com/views/home.html
```

Would be no different than accessing:

```
test.example.com/views/home.html
```